# Having trouble with layout

Tags: magento-1.9

I can't figure out why mine doesn't look like the example theme

MINE

http://cocochella.com/shop/clothing/dresses/asd.html

EXAMPLE

http://demo.meigeeteam.com/blacknwhite-magento-theme/english/jacket-with-detachable-fur.html

The options are spread out at the bottom and the facebook and twitter icons are gone. It is only for Configurable Product. My simple products look fine.

cocochella.com/shop/jewerly/necklaces/long-trible-black-bead-pendant-necklace.html

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Catalog > Manage Products` open the configurable product and then look for `Display Product Options In` under the `Design` tab. Here you can set it to `Product Info Column`.

[image]

Save the product and check your frontend. It should look like the demo now.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out all night. Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to accept my answer as correct and mark this question as answered.